# Is there a way to initialize a file that hasnt been read yet in c

Tags: c

For my project we are supposed to read a file and copy it in reverse. The part I am stumped on is how I can get the program to read the file off the command line, because I have no idea what file will be used to test this, and I don't have the given txt file. Is there a way to assign a variable to file that hasn't been declared yet and to create a new file that shows the reverse txt? Sorry if this is not clear, I will try to make it as clear as possible if you need me to.

Comment: you want to read from stdin or read an argument from args and open a file based on that?

Comment: You can use `argc` and `argv` arguments of `main` to read the filename from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the file name in using the argv[] array that is declared when you create main. Because fopen in C takes a char, or char array you can then open the file specified through the command line. For all the information you should need regarding this use the site I link.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html

Answer (score 0):

From command line you can pass file to write some thing and file which will be reversed

```
Your program looks like  

int main(int argc,char *argv[] )
{
//...
return 0;
}
```

compile

```
  gcc program.c -o out
```

You need to pass files like this

```
 ./out file_to_write file_to_write_in_reverse
```

------------------------------------------------------------or---------------------------------------------------------------------

In Your Program

use `fgets()` and read file name of file_to_write

You can create a file.

```
 fopen()+ w+ mode
```

Write data, for example write string into file

```
`fprintf()` or `fputs()`
```

use `fgets()` and read another file name of file_to_write_in_reverse

create file_to_write_in_reverse

```
fopen()+ w mode
```

and now Use `fseek()`, `fgetc()` and `fputc()`

Comment: Ok thanks so i open with open(args[1], "r"); to read it. Also Im not supposed to used fopen(), fread(), fwrite(), etc. but from my understanding i can use just open(), write() and read() in its place right?

Comment: Yes You can use `open()`, `write()` and `read()` instead. if you want to open file in read mode file should be exists. if you want to create file use open with write mode.